# Android Navigation Drawer with a flap or semi-closed?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

Can i create a Navigation Drawer with a part visibile when it is close? Like a bookmark, a flap.
I want to show a flap when drawer is closed otherwise i want create a semi-closed drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Navigation drawer as mentioned here:https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

If you want something more then please elaborate more.

Comment: I have already implemented the drawer. I would like display part of menu when it is closed. Like a bookmark, a flap.